# Tuning PHP exception reporting similar to error reporting

Tags: php, exception, error-reporting

For Apache web server, we can tune the error reporting via `error_reporting` entry in `php.ini`.

Is there a similar setting for exception reporting?

My below code show that `error_reporting` doesn't effect `exception throw` command.

```
function actionTestThrow() {
    error_reporting(null);
    $i=122;        
    throw new Exception('abb');
    $i=344;        
    echo $i;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions are always fatal. You can't just hide them. If you want to ignore an exception, you'll need to handle it in a `try catch` block.

---

What you can do, is extend the exception class (`FatalException`, `NoticeException`) etc, and handle each differently, more on that on **[Extending Exceptions](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php)**

Answer (score 2):

I think you should wrap your function calls or function body with `try/catch` block, and when exception is caught just use `trigger_error` function in order to move error through the error_reporting mechanism of php

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can set custom exception handler

```
function exception($e) {
var_dump($e); 
}

set_exception_handler ( 'exception' );
```